# How do i transfer control information between windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to know how do i transfer multiple information between windows in WPF.

So far I have this:

Main form:

```
string path = @"C:\";
private void preview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        preview newWindow = new preview(Path);
        newWindow.Show();
    }
```

The preview form:

```
public preview(string _path) {
        InitializeComponent();
        Path = _path;                 
    }
```

But this only allows me to send one piece of information at a time. How would I send multiple information at one time?

Comment: is there a particular reason why you can't use multiple parameters in your Preview constructor? e.g. public preview(string path, int a, string b, string c)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're sticking to that particular design, then you can send information in a `class` or a `struct`, which you would pass instead of the `string`:

```
preview newWindow = new preview(data);

public preview(CustomData data) { ... }
```

Or just pass multiple arguments if your constructor accepts multiple parameters:

```
preview newWindow = new preview(path, somethingElse, somethingMore);

public preview(string path, int somethingElse, int somethingMore) { ... }
```

I just prefer to keep things nice and tight if I work with some sort of collection of data a lot, that's why I recommended `class` or `struct`.  However, if pieces of information have no particular relation to each other beyond being passed together, then multiple parameters approach works just fine.

Comment: how do i use it in the other window? I have 3 fields `int a` `string b` and `string c` how would i use them in preview?

Comment: @FahadJameel `data.a`, `data.b`, `data.c`. You would store them as fields or properties and access through the dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your three values in a three parameter constructor of preview class.

```
    string path = @"C:\";
    private void preview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            preview newWindow = new preview(1,"string1","String2");
            newWindow.Show();
        }

    The preview form:
    int a;
    string b;
    string c;

    public preview(int _a, string _b, string _c) 
{
            InitializeComponent();
                   this.a=_a;
                   this.b=_b;
                   this.c=_c;  
        }
```

If you have to pass more values to Preview form I would suggest you should create a DTO class that will contain all the values you want to pass to preview form. Create instance of DTO class on your mainform and set values as required and pass this DTO class to preview form and on preview form you can have a custructor that will accept this dto class.